# issue with datatable with columnFilter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatable, datatables

I have problem with datable server side after columns Filter or pagination. Firstly, after reload page - all fine, data get correctly. But after then i sorting or filtering columns, request url return error.

Here is my jquery:

```
var customer_id = $('input[name=customer-id]').val();

// Data tables
$('#customers-list-data').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '/customers/edit/'+customer_id,
    columns: [
        { data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name' },
        { data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name' },
        { data: 'phone', name: 'phone' },
        { data: 'country', name: 'country' },
        { data: 'city', name: 'city' },
        { data: 'address', name: 'address' },
        { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
        { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
    ],
pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    dom: '<"dt-top-row"Bfl>r<"dt-wrapper"t><"dt-row dt-bottom-row"<"row"<"col-sm-6"i><"col-sm-6 text-right"p>>>',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Save <span class="caret" />',
            buttons : ['csvFlash', 'excelFlash', 'pdfFlash']
        },
        'colvis'
    ]
});

$('#customers-list-data').dataTable().columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
    aoColumns: [
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        null
    ]
});
```

And this is method on laravel project:

```
public function getEdit(Request $request, Customer $customer)
{   
    if($request->ajax()) {

        $customer_data = $customer->Data()->get();

        return Datatables::of($customer_data)
                ->addColumn('action', function ($customer_data) {
                    return '<div class="btn-group">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <a href="'.url('customers/delete_one/'.$customer_data->id.'/'.$customer_data->customers_id).'" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            </div>';
                })
                ->make(true);
    }
}
```

First time request url :

```
http://address.com/customers/edit/39?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=first_name&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=first_name ...
```

After filtering or sorting, pagination:

```
http://address.com/customers/edit/39?draw=2&columns=%5Bobject+Object%5D%2C%5Bobject+Object%5D%2C%5Bobject+Object%5D%2C%5Bobject+Object%5D%2C%5Bobject+Object%5D%2C%5Bobject+Object%5D%2C%5Bobject+Object%5D%2C%5Bobject+Object%5D&order=%5Bobject+Object%5D&start=10&length=10&search=%5Bobject+Object%5D&sRangeSeparator=~
```

Laravel debug error:

```
in Request.php line 78
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Illegal string offset 'column'', '/var/www/dev/vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/yajra/Datatables/Request.php', '78', array('orderable' => array(), 'i' => '0', 'c' => '1')) in Request.php line 78
```

Here is my table:

```html
<table id="customers-list-data" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover customers-table-list">
  <thead>
    <tr class="second">
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 11%;">First Name</th>
      <th style="width: 11%;">Last Name</th>
      <th style="width: 11%;">Phone</th>
      <th style="width: 11%;">Country</th>
      <th style="width: 11%;">City</th>
      <th style="width: 11%;">Address</th>
      <th style="width: 11%;">Email</th>
      <th class="no-sort" style="width: 13%;">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I using libraries:

Laravel

```
http://datatables.yajrabox.com/
```

JS

```
 http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
 http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js
```

I think its a bug of these versions, because with older datatable version is good.

Comment: Not sure about columnFilter.js , but you can use [my yadcf plugin](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf) for filtering, [here a showcase](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html) using serverside setup with yadcf

Comment: In the request parameters for the URL after sorting, you have a bunch of these: `object+Object`. This tells me that you're not getting the right values into variables that populate the parameters. Have you looked into this?

Comment: yes i saw this, but why after filtering columns variables are not correct? maybe error because in thead are 2 rows?